# Setting a float to a more precise number than it can store

Tags: c#, converters

Can someone explain how this works?

```
float f = -1.8033077716827393f;
Console.WriteLine("f=" + f);
double d = (double)f;
Console.WriteLine("d=" + d);

Output is:
f=-1.8033078
d=-1.8033077716827393
```

[Microsoft says floats only support 9 digits of precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single), so by that logic, shouldn't the extra precision be lost when you save the -1.8033077716827393 to a float? How does it show the full number when you cast it to a double?

Reason I ask is because I'm reading in a binary data format. The format says this is a 4 byte real, which should be a float in c#. The two python readers I've been using show -1.8033077716827393 in that variable. In this c# one, it is showing -1.8033078 (rounded up), but when I cast it to a double it comes up with the -1.8033077716827393.

Edit: I figured it out. The number is special. I added an answer to this below.

Comment: I don't want to take the time to type out a full answer, but "9 digits of (decimal) precision" is not a very accurate way to describe how floating point works. There should be at least a few asterisks and links there in the docs (even if it's links to farther down in the same doc). I think Microsoft made a bit of a blunder there. I also am not going to read Microsoft's entire doc to make sure it's good, but I think this third party guide (and the pages it links to, especially) would more likely be useful: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @hans Passant - The document I linked says "Yes. Double supports 17 decimal digits of precision; Single supports 9."  A float is a single.  Microsoft documentation says you edited my question to be less accurate

Comment: Quote: *A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally*.  Do not convert back to decimal and you'd have a point.  Misleading programmers about what is possible is not helpful. The answer is otherwise simple. Precision is normally expressed as, say, +/-0.001%.  That includes 0% off.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the extra precision be lost when you save the -1.8033077716827393 to a float?

-1.8033077716827393, due to being the result of converting a float to a decimal string, is non-coincidentally very close to a value that can be represented exactly by a float. The actual value that is stored in the float is -1.8033077716827392578125, very close. Much closer than what tends to happen when some arbitrary decimal string was converted to a float, because the particular decimal string -1.8033077716827393 was the result of converting a float to a string to begin with (with more digits printed than usual) - so of course it *had* to be close.

The length of those numbers in decimal is not representative of the precision, the two neighbouring numbers are a distance of 2<sup>-23</sup> away (since this number is in the [-1..-2) binade). There are still only 24 bits of precision, it's just that converting to decimal causes significant expansion.

Here is a more extreme example, namely the smallest normal (ie not subnormal) float:

```
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625
```

Since that is the result of converting a float to a string to begin with (printing more digits than normally would be done), it can be converted back to a float losslessly. Whether that is really meaningful is a different question..

> How does it show the full number when you cast it to a double?

The full number was actually -1.8033077716827392578125, but having the number as a `double` (still the same value, as a different type) makes `WriteLine` (with default formatting) print more digits than when it was a float. You can generate even more digits and even do an exact conversion, I don't know of any built-in way to do that in C# but you can do it manually for example with Jon Skeet's [double converter](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs).

Comment: Yes, okay I see. Very interesting. (*understands not a single word*)

Comment: @RandRandom can you be more specific, I really did try to make this understandable but I may not have hit the mark

Comment: I think the way it works under the hood isn't very intuitive so making people understand it is hard.

Comment: Ok. The short of it is that this number is just special.  You can change the digits after the 777 in the initial float and when you convert it to a double, it comes up with the original number before I edited it.

Comment: @Migit well yes. But it's not very special, -1.80330789089202880859375 should do it too, and really, most floats in general when they have a fairly long decimal representation. Changing them by a small enough amount means that they get rounded back to what it was before, but the original number is *by construction* something that doesn't need rounding (since it was originally a float).

Comment: It's special in the way that tons of numbers will round up to that specific number.

Comment: @Migit for any given float, there are tons of numbers that round to it, namely every number that is closer to that float than to any other float. Every float has such as "region of attraction" around it, the size of which depends on the exponent of the float (and there are some fun asymmetric cases near the numbers where the exponent changes)

Answer (score 2):

Harold's answer is very complete. I'm going to take a shot at explaining it more simply.

Similar to decimal, binary is great at precisely representing some numbers ("1/2") but terrible at representing other numbers (like "1/3").

```
Console.WriteLine(1 / 3f);         // 0.33333334
```

When you convert an imprecise `float` value to `double`, you see a lot more of the imprecision because double's `ToString()` implementation assumes you want to see more decimal places. This isn't adding or maintaining precision: it's just adding digits that highlight the original imprecision.

```
Console.WriteLine((double)(1/3f)); // 0.3333333432674408
```

But if you chose a number in the first place which looked just like the number you'd have ended up with, it *looks* like you magically retained precision.

```
Console.WriteLine((double)(0.3333333432674408f)); // 0.3333333432674408
```

That's what happened in this case. You could have used `-1.80330778f` in your code and ended up with the exact same output.